# No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.Class<org.springframework.data.repository.Repository<?, ?>>' available

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I use spring data jpa (using CrudRepository interface) in my project and have declared my repository interface like this :

```
/**
 * Repository implementation {@link CrudRepository}  for {@link Client} entity
 * @author rsone.
 */
public interface ClientRepository extends CrudRepository<Client, Integer> {
}
```

And have my hibernate config like bellow :

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.rsone.mga.*" />

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.rsone.mga.repository" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory" transaction-manager-ref="hibernateTransactionManager"/>

<bean id="datasource" parent="abstractDataSource">
    <property name="dataSourceName" value="mgaDS" />
    <property name="driverClass" value="${database.mga.jdbc.driver}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${database.mga.jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${database.mga.jdbc.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.mga.jdbc.pass}" />
    <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL" />
</bean>    <bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <property name="fetchSize" value="5000" />
    <property name="cacheQueries" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
    <!-- spring based scanning for entity classes>-->
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.scor.mga.db"/>
</bean>

<!-- Enables the Hibernate @Transactional programming model -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" />

<bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
    <!--<property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>-->
    <property name="database" value="SQL_SERVER"/>
</bean>
```

But When I try to run my project it give me that error (knowing that the base package of my repositories is com.rsone.mga.repository) :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.Class<org.springframework.data.repository.Repository<?, ?>>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1466)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1097)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1059)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
```

---

**Edit**

I use version 1.11.0.RELEASE of spring-data-jpa:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in my maven project.

**So this below is not working**

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

together with

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

**Solution**

It was solved by updating to the newest Spring boot release :

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Doing this already solved the problem.

It looks like the spring data tags are not backwards compatible with previous versions (other than the managed version). 
So I would also recommend removing the version tag from the spring-data-cassandra dependency. Apparently Spring boot 1.5.1.RELEASE manages spring-data-cassandra 1.5.0.RELEASE.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be an error in your configuration files.

It look like you have an @Autowired on a field of type `java.lang.Class<org.springframework.data.repository.Repository<?, ?>>` in one of the beans that are scanned.

Comment: yes I Autowire the ClientRepository in another bean like this `@Autowired
    ClientRepository clientRepository;` it isn't the right way ?

Comment: It's strange because I've declared the repository base package in the config file, so it should detect my repo automatically without the need of `@Repository` annotation that means it should be autowired using `@Autowired` !!

Comment: It is the right way and i think it works well. Search every field that have `@Autowired` annotations and i think you will find a field of type `Class` and your Spring Context does not contain any bean of that type.